# threeJS jsonLoader - "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm creating a scene, which can be saved and then loaded.

To save the scene,I serialize all the objects (and their data). For the meshes this works simply like this:

```
var json = {};
json.objectsInScene = [];
for (var i = 0; i < collectionOfObjects.length; i++)
{
 
    json.objectsInScene.push(collectionOfObjects[i].toJSON();
}
```

Then, I try to load them back in which works like this:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);

for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.objectsInScene.length;i++){
    
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    var geometry = loader.parse(jsonObject.objectsInScene[i]);

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial());

    this.scene.add(mesh);
}
```

When I execute this code. I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> Line 14990 of three.js.

Which is this line:

```
zLength = vertices.length;
```

And when checking it in the dev tools, I have to agree: vertices.length is `undefined`. In fact, it gets assigned a couple of lines above that:

```
var vertices = json.vertices;
```

But the json-object only contains the following properties:

```
geometries: Array[15]
materials: Array[15]
metadata: Object
object: Object
```

What am I doing wrong? Where does it go wrong, or what can I do to work around this issue?

R73

Comment: are any of your JSON call asynchronous?

Comment: @gaitat no, they are called one after each other, without any async options.

Comment: after your `loader.parse()` call, is `geometry.geometry.vertices` defined?

Comment: @gaitat It gets stuck on that line: the error I get are inside the `loader.parse()` call. (which leads to line 14990 of three.js)

Comment: so then there is a problem with your `jsonObject.objectsInScene[i]` object(s). Maybe you need to create a fiddle. We cannot see the objects otherwise.

Comment: I will look to make a jsFiddle, but the objects in the array are created by just doing  `collectionOfObjects[i].toJSON()` for each object in my scene.

Comment: yes I have seen that but there is no way to debug the posted code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101410/discussion-between-jordumus-and-gaitat).

Comment: I wish you had posted the answer to this. I have the exact same problem but am using R105 and The now LegacyJSONLoader!

Answer (score -2):

maybe you should use **THREE.ObjectLoader**

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonObject.objectsInScene.length;i++){

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    var obj= loader.parse(jsonObject.objectsInScene[i]);

    this.scene.add(obj);
}
```